# Cannot send email from Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, jakarta-mail, playframework-2.2

I am trying to use Play Framework to send out email. In applications.conf, when I set smtp.mock=true , it works perfectly well:

```
[info] application - HTML: Welcome to Play20StartApp. <br> Click on this link : http://localhost:9000/confirm/d77ea256-0d2e-4df5-b66e-e034159f8042 to confirm your email.<br><br>--<br>null
[debug] application - Mail sent - SMTP:smtp.google.com:465 SSL:yes user:username@gmail.com password:password
```

However, when I comment smtp.mock=true and attempt to send real emails, I get this error:

```
[debug] application - Mail.sendMail: Mail will be sent to user1@gmail.com
[ERROR] [09/26/2013 03:46:05.014] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [TaskInvocation] From address required
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: From address required
```

I have set smtp.user to a proper value, i.e. server@businessdomain.com . Any idea what causes this error?

Troubleshooting steps

1. The emails used are real emails, for the purpose of posting, they are anonymized. Likewise, a real domain name is used
2. Tested with a working local mail server (exim), as well as directly sending through Gmail (smtp.google.com) and Google Apps (aspmx.l.google.com) servers. These settings have been verified using mail clients.
3. The Java code snippet below works perfectly,

   import java.util.*;
       import javax.mail.*;
       import javax.mail.internet.*;
       import javax.activation.*;

   ```
   public class SendEmail
   {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
           String to = "recipient@mydomain.com";
           String from = "sender@mydomain.com";
           String host = "localhost";

           Properties properties = System.getProperties();

           // Setup mail server
           properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

           // Get the default Session object.
           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

           try{
               MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

               // Set From: header field of the header.
               message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

               message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                       new InternetAddress(to));
               message.setSubject("Subject of email");
               message.setText("This is actual message");

               Transport.send(message);
               System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
           }catch (MessagingException mex) {
               mex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I know nothing about the Play Framework; is it not using the (working) Java code you posted above?  Are you actually setting the From address in the email message, or just the SMTP user name to authenticate with?

Comment: No, it is not using the Java code. I used that Java code with the exact email configuration (from, to, smtp server) just to make sure the problem is not with the SMTP/transport bit. 

i.e. Plain javax.mail works. When I try to send email from Play Framework it fails and complain about invalid form address.

Comment: Then my guess is that you need to tell the Play Framework to set the From address, but just the SMTP user.

Comment: @BillShannon That is correct. Which is what I did in the application.conf file

smtp.host=smtp.google.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.from="my.email@gmail.com"

That did not work.

Comment: Looks like you need a Play Framework expert.  Try posting on the [Play Framework users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework).

Comment: @hanxue Did you ever sort this out? Hitting the same issue in Play 2.2 Scala

Comment: @virtualeyes not yet. Currently using `smtp.mock=true`

Comment: @hanxue ok, well, "sending" mock mails won't help much in production ;-) Since play mailer only exposes setters we have no idea if fromAddress is actually being set. Play user group has zero feedback on this issue ;-( Would like to use the mailer plugin, but if it's broken, plain Java utility will have to do.

Comment: @hanxue I provided the solution to what caused the mailer plugin to fail in my case; not sure if you're hitting the same (sending mail in Future context)

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are wrapping your mailer action in a Future (or Play Java equivalent), then it may be a variable scoping issue that you're hitting:

This works:

```
val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
val async: Future[Unit] = Future{
  mail.setSubject(subject)
  mail.setRecipient(recipient)
  mail.setFrom(from)
  mail.send(body)
}
async.onFailure{case(e)=>
  Logger.error(s"mailer failed for $recipient due to: ${e.getMessage}")
}
```

This does *not* work:

```
val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
mail.setSubject(subject)
mail.setRecipient(recipient)
mail.setFrom(from)
val async: Future[Unit] = Future{mail.send(body)}
async.onFailure{case(e)=>
  Logger.error(s"mailer failed for $recipient due to: ${e.getMessage}")
}
```

I assumed that the enclosing scope would be available within the Future closure; in this case definitely not since underlying Apache Commons mailer bails with "From address required". Sure enough, setting smtp.mock=true reveals that fromAddress is null when mail.setFrom and friends are populated outside of Future{...} scope.

Interestingly, even if I break out async val into a local method and pass in constructed mailer and body text:

```
private def async(mail: MailerAPI, body: String): Future[Unit] = Future{
  mail.send(body)
}
```

the mail properties set outside of the Future still wind up null despite passing a constructed mailer directly -- surprising, no?